# can I output the records that is not inserted error "ignore/Skip duplicate keys sql server "

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have this  insert into statement to copy value from select tables join . the select get 3000 records but when we run it. it ignore/Skip duplicate keys and inserted 2990 rows

```
insert into (col1,col2,col3,col4)
(select col1,col2 col3,col4  from  a FULL  OUTER JOIN  b ON a.ID = b.ID)
```

I have to ask how can I copy data without losing record , can I output the records that is not inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing  you have to use the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) TSQl and make ouytput like this

```
BEGIN TRY
--your sql MERGE here 

 OUTPUT $action, inserted.*,deleted.*;

Commit
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
     ROLLBACK

    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
       RETURN;
END CATCH
GO
```